# Need some tips in jquery / json for arrays in photo viewer

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm making a photo viewer from scratch and it is working fine, except a few things.

The code goes like this:

First I have the ID of the current album, and print all the images belonging to the photo. Then, when user click on the photo, this happened:

```
    var loaded = [];
    var albums = [];
        var album_id = ALBUM ID
    var cur_pic = 0;
    var alb_name = ''; 
    $('.photo').click(function(){
    var cover_photo = $(this).attr('id').replace("911","");


        albums[album_id] = [];

        $('#photo_preview .pleft').html('<img src="'+cover_photo+'"/>');
        $('#photo_preview').show();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "photo_ajax.php",
        dataType:'json',
        data: 'action=get_info' + $('#aid').val().replace("aid",""),    
        success: function(data){

        loaded[album_id] = true;
        albums[album_id] = data;

    $('#photo_preview .pleft').html('<img src="'+albums[album_id][0]['ImagePath']+'"/>'); // The first photo you click on, will be the first photo to see :)
       $('#photo_preview').show();

            }
        })
//  }       
});

// Loading images and make them visible in the popup...

function loadNextImage(album_id, step){
function loadNextImage(album_id, step){

var next_pic = 0;

        if(step == 0){

            next_pic = 0;

        }else if(step == 'next'){


            next_pic = parseInt(cur_pic, 10)+1;
            cur_pic = next_pic;

        if(next_pic >= albums[album_id].length){
                next_pic = 0;
            }

        }else{

            next_pic = parseInt(cur_pic, 10)-1;

            if(next_pic < 0){
                next_pic = albums[album_id].length - 1;
            }
        }
        cur_pic = next_pic;

        $('#photo_preview .pleft').html('<img src="'+albums[album_id][next_pic]['ImagePath']+'"/>');
    }


// Loading the next image in the JSON array...:

    $(".preview_next").click(function(){

        loadNextImage(album_id, 'next');

    });


// Loading the previous image in the JSON array...:

    $(".preview_prev").click(function(){

        loadNextImage(album_id, 'prev');

    });
```

In photo_ajax.php:

```
    $i = 0; $album = array();

    foreach( $aImageInfo as $row ){

            $album[$i] = array();

            $album[$i]['ImageID'] = $row['ImageID'];

            $album[$i]['ImagePath'] = $row['ImagePath'];

            $album[$i]['ImageDate'] = $row['ImageDate'];

            $album[$i]['ImageDescription'] = $row['ImageDescription'];

            $i++;
        }
        echo json_encode($album);
```

This is working, but my questions are now this:

1. var cur_pic = 0; is set to 0, mean it will start to show the first photo in the json array. I need it fixed so I can find witch number in the array the photo I just clicked on is, so it can start to view and count from that spot.
2. This is now only working inside a album. Say I have a single photo visible on another page. How to fix this so - when I click on it - the photo is visible and I can get the whole json array, and browse through all images belonging to the same album as the photo I have clicked on.

Straight example. Say Facebook or Twitter. You have a photo on the wall. Click on it, and you can navigate whole album.

How to solve?

Comment: I figure out how to find the number of the current value in the array, so now I need to find a solution to question number 2.

I used a for loop running through the array, and returned the value when it matched the ID on the image.

Answer (score 1):

I was litle confussed this morning, but the answer is clear now. First thing that need to be done, is sending the image ID into the jquery function that open up the image viewer. Then when I get the result back from the AJAX call, I simple do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < albums[album_id].length; i++) {

    if(albums[album_id][i]['ImageID'] == imgId){

        var newStep = i;    
    }
}
```

Then I will get the correct position in the json array. Then I can follow this up, and get the correct photo viewable with this code:

```
albums[album_id][newStep]['ImagePath']
```

If I want to get the same result when the photo is viewable outside the album - on a single page. The solution should now be pretty clear. I send in both the ID for the album, and ID for the photo. Then I use AJAX in the same way and get the JSON array.

And let the user see the photo. User can now navigate in the album without see the other images, because they are in the array.

Litle extra. For getting the navigation info like this:  Photo 20 of 110, I did this:

```
$('#PhotoViewerBottomBarContent').html(parseInt(cur_pic+1)+' of '+albums[album_id].length);
```

I had to had +1 because an array allways start with 0.

So the solution was simple :)